# Need Information about Latest Chrome Driver Setup

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Previously while launching Chrome Driver we were using system `set property` by using chromedriver.exe file or `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()` command.

But now with latest version of Chrome without using the command `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()` it is working fine. Is there any latest configuration for that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes your observation is correct. i.e. Now selenium doesn't need `System.setProperty` or third party library like `WebDriverManager` to handle the browsers/browser drivers.

In selenium `v4.6.0` and above, selenium has introduced a tool known as Selenium Manager, this will handle the browser and browser driver for you. This means you don't need to download `driver.exe` or `WebDriverManager` separately.

For detailed information, refer the below official source.

[Selenium 4.6.0 Released!](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/selenium-4-6-0-released/)

[Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)